# Is there a way to create an S3 static website on the main domain name & not the www subdomain?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, dns, nameservers

I created a static website using an aws s3 bucket named [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) and linked to a godaddy domain via Route 53. Also created a bucket named example.com that redirects to the [www.example.com](http://www.example.com).  All good on that side.

However when I go directly to example.com (without the www), the website doesn't come up (Error is: DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN). However, when I go to [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) first and then example.com, that seems to do it - I believe the browser is able to read from the cache?

Is there a way to make sure example.com is reachable directly?

I thought about doing things the other way round - that is, using example.com bucket as the main website and [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) as for redirect, but I can't seem to find any tutorials where it's done this way. Everyone seems to include the subdomain www. in the bucket name

Is that because it's impossible to do it that way?

Comment: Please show us how you have configured the `example.com` domain name, both in GoDaddy and in Amazon Route 53. The main procedures to follow are: [Tutorial: Configuring a static website using a custom domain registered with Route 53 - Amazon Simple Storage Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/website-hosting-custom-domain-walkthrough.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I thought about doing things the other way round - that is, using example.com bucket as the main website and [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) as for redirect

Should not cause any issues. Even i am using s3, r53 for static website hosting. My bucket name is [www.mydomain.com](http://www.mydomain.com)

However, I have also used cloudfront for better distribution. So whenever i type mydomain.com it opens my webpage.

Maybe create a record in your route53 to redirect example.com to [www.expample.com](http://www.expample.com)?

Comment: Yes this did it, thanks. I didn't use cloudfront at first and then found a tutorial that explained how to do that!

Only slight hiccup now is it's not accessable to IP address outside of the Americas & Eurrope. That doesn't bother me much as I don't expect much traffic from outside these regions. I'm just curious as to why this is the case.

Comment: Check your cloudfront distribution settings. you have option in 'Price Class' . 

You might have chosen 'Use only North America & Europe' instead of 'Use all Edge locations' 

Click on you distribution > Settings > edit > choose correct price class

Comment: Yes that was my first thought as well, but that's not where the problem is apparently